# Nuxt axios request without cookies specific uri

Tags: axios

This project is on nuxtjs.
I don't think is important but maybe it can be some clue.

I need to get order detail information for using axios and below url.
`/users/orders/d/20210806000349`

but, very weird because axios doesn't request without cookies that url

of course i do set `withCredentials: true` already

when i change that url to `/20210806000349` everyting is okay

someone help me about this?

Comment: are nuxt domain and api domain equal? please give me domains and set-cookie header options for more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figure out myself

`get` request also preflight `options` request if domain is different

but in this case chrome doesn't show up `options` request

i check this on firefox

Answer (score 1):

I need more detail about domains but maybe api domain and nuxt domain are different. in this case you should care about **CORS**.

### what is CORS

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain, scheme, or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading of resources. CORS also relies on a mechanism by which browsers make a "preflight" request to the server hosting the cross-origin resource, in order to check that the server will permit the actual request. In that preflight, the browser sends headers that indicate the HTTP method and headers that will be used in the actual request.
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

### what happen if you request to foreign domain?

1. user agent send an `option` request to foreign host
2. foreign host send response whit some header
3. user agent looks to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header and if its value is not equal to your domain block request
4. if request's `withCredentials` be true look at `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header and if its value be true send request with cookie. otherwise send request without cookie.